# Eclipse JAR at runtime

Tags: eclipse, jar

I'm importing several JARs all sitting in the same directory. When my program runs I'm able to access the classes in several of those JARs, no problem. So my classpath is fine (I assume). But there is one JAR giving me trouble. When I try to run:

```
Configuration conf = new BaseConfiguration();
```

I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` error. The searching I did on "`NoClassDefFound`" typically points to classpath problems but as mentioned above, other JARs in the same directory are being found so I think that's not the problem.

This is in Eclipse 3.8.

The import statements:

```
import org.apache.commons.configuration.BaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration;
```

And the name of the JAR is:

```
commons-configuration-1.6.jar
```

Any ideas?

Tom

Comment: Are you *sure* you didn't mispell the JAR's name? Are you *sure* that JAR *actually* has that Configuration class? From the looks of it, you're doing everything through Eclipse. Is that the case?

Comment: Misspelling is the first thing I checked: if you misspell either the class or JAR, then Eclipse flags it and it won't compile. So I'm ok there. Yes, this is all in Eclipse...thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's failing to load a dependency of one of the classes in `commons-configuration-1.6.jar`?  Maybe from another `commons-` JAR?  The `NoClassDefFoundError` should tell you which class the runtime failed to load.  Have you checked this?

Comment: Mike you are the man, that was it. I needed to add several JARs. Thanks much.